# Finding constants so that inequality holds

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

Find $b > 0$ such that $b^x \geqslant x + 1$ holds for all $x$ values of $x$.

This is apparently related to differentiation but since you can’t differentiate inequalities, I don’t know how this works.

Answer (score 2):

Well, on how to use derivatives here, note we want to show $f(x) = b^x-x-1\geqslant 0$.  So we want the minimum of $f$ to be non-negative.

Extrema are when $f'=0$.  As $f(0)=0$, you want an extremum to be at $x=0$, and that too it needs to be a minimum, so we need $f'(0) = 0, \; f''(0)>0$.
$f'(x) = \log b \cdot b^x -1 \implies  f'(0) = 0$ iff $b=e$.  Now $f''(0) = e^0>0$ and so we have a unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture of $x+1$ and $5^x$  and $\left( \frac{5}{4} \right)^x$

Note how both curves are sometimes below the straight line.

What needs to happen so that $b^x$  is always above or touching the line? It  touches when $x=0$

[image]